# Use variables as a selector Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, selector

```
 var my_link = "#portfolio-link-"+data[i].pf_id;
```

I save a id inside of a variable.

```
("#pf-container-1").append(portfolio);

    console.log(my_link);
    $(my_link).append(function(){

        $("<button class='btn btn-inverse' id='portfolio-link-"+data[i].pf_id+"'>more</button>").click(handler);

         });
```

Then i try to append a button to this #id (my_link)

it outputs me the correct data on console.log(my_link)

but it does not append the button inside of this selected element...

My Question: How can I use variables as selector?

I even tired to write the whole value of my_link inside of the $() but it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using a function inside of append?

Comment: A string is a string, there's nothing stopping a variable from being used as a selector.  Maybe something else is wrong with your code...

Comment: @epascarello A function can be used as parameter to `.append()` , as long as a value is returned from function

Comment: double ids perhaps? I see `"#portfolio-link-"+data[i].pf_id` occuring twice in your code snippet. Might be worth validating your markup, since double ids can produce strange js behavior...

Comment: @epascarello because a dynamically added element can not call a on() or click() function.

Comment: @Pevara THANKS you are right! the problem was that thought when i am returning the value it stops the for loop(i dont know why i thought that because it is just a function that returns a value!) But now that i added return in front it works perfectly fine. If you add your Answer below i will mark it. I change the title and the describtion because it was not a problem with the selectors...

Comment: @LukasA it has nothing to do with dynamically added with on/click.  That function has zero benefit to you in this case.

Comment: @epascarello off course it has to do with dynamically added elements. try to create a button dynamically with append. and then try to make a function where you read out the id of this element when you click it. it does not work. so you have to create the .click() function inside of the append(). handler is in this case my function who reads this id... If you know a different way please tell me...

Comment: Yes, you could drop the function(){} and it would work. `.append( $("<button>foo</button").on("click", function(){ alert("click"); }) );`

Comment: @LukasA https://jsfiddle.net/7xdwkco1/

Answer (score 0):

I unfortunately don't really understand the code. But maybe this will help:

```
var my_link = "#portfolio-link-"+data[i].pf_id;
var btn_id = 'portfolio-link-'+data[i].pf_id; // Button has the same id with my_link element?
var btn = '<button class="btn btn-inverse" id="'+btn_id+'">more</button>';
$(my_link).append(btn);
$('#'+btn_id).on('click', handler);
```

Comment: I don't know. The question did not have this function.